# Flutter - Persist data in Integration Tests

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, persistence

I am using the package [get_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/get_storage) to persist some data in my app like login and retrieve some objects, when I run integration tests the data are always null and because of that I always need to login and download some data before making some tests.

Is it possible to run integration tests keeping the data from the app?

Comment: Hi, I need this also to persist permission grants.

Comment: I ended up creating mocks for storages to finish integratiin test.